# What OOP pattern do I use to provide defaults without violating the Liskov substitution principle

Tags: php, oop

I have a class that controls an external API that I use in several projects (simplified example):

```
class PaymentModule
{
  public function doPayment($customer_name, $currency, $language)
  {
    curl_setopt(POSTFIELDS, array($customer_name, $currence, $language));
    curl_exec();
  }
}
```

Now in a specific project I would like to "wrap" it and provide sensible defaults for a lot of parameters that I don't use here.

So I thought, I will just `extend` this class, have my IDE override all methods and then remove the parameters that I don't use, like this:

```
class MyPaymentModule extends PaymentModule
{
  public function doPayment($customer_name)
  {
    $language = get_current_language();
    parent::doPayment($customer_name, 'EUR', $language);
  }
}
```

As I now learned (thanks to PHP strict standards), this violates the Liskov substitution principle, i.e. in OOP in general `MyPaymentModule` is expected to have the same interface as `PaymentModule` which in turn means `MyPaymentModule::doPayment()` is expected to have the same parameters as `PaymentModule::doPayment()`.

I think it's not too uncommon that you want to create a class that provides sensible defaults to another one, so is there any common pattern to use here?
Of course I could go for two completely independent classes, but I would prefer a solution that still hints at the relationship between the two classes... after all they will always have the same methods, just one with *less* parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not possible with your current class design.
I would suggest to create a new class PaymentOptions which handles currency and language.
Passing the options to doPayment either with a new method setPaymentOptions or as an optional parameter for doPayment.

Something like this should work

```
class PaymentModule {

    /**
     * @var PaymentOptions
     */
    private $paymentOptions = null;

    function doPayment($customer_name, PaymentOptions $options = null) {
        if ($options == null) {
            $options = $this->paymentOptions;
        }
        if ($options == null) {
            throw new Exception('...');
        }

        //...
    }

    /**
     * @return PaymentOptions
     */
    public function getPaymentOptions()
    {
        return $this->paymentOptions;
    }

    /**
     * @param PaymentOptions $paymentOptions
     */
    public function setPaymentOptions($paymentOptions)
    {
        $this->paymentOptions = $paymentOptions;
    }

}

class MyPaymentModule extends PaymentModule {

    function doPayment($customer_name, PaymentOptions $options = null)
    {
        //...
    }

}

class PaymentOptions {
    private $currency;
    private $language;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $currency
     */
    public function setCurrency($currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $language
     */
    public function setLanguage($language)
    {
        $this->language = $language;
    }
}
```